Elementwise subtract one dataframe from another with different number of columns
I have a dataframe:
df
            East  Midwest  Mountain
2015-01-02   737      849       152
2015-01-09   685      774       142
2015-01-16   631      711       136
2015-01-23   595      677       134

That I'd like to subtract a second dataframe from to create a resulting dataframe of differences.
dy
            East_5yavg  Midwest_5yavg  Mountain_5yavg  East_max  Midwest_max  Mountain_max
2015-01-02       755.0          867.0           187.0     838.0        946.0         200.0
2015-01-09       706.0          807.0           178.0     807.0        909.0         192.0
2015-01-16       662.0          754.0           170.0     764.0        865.0         181.0
2015-01-23       616.0          696.0           163.0     708.0        808.0         174.0

df - dy
            East_x  Midwest_x  Mountain_x  East_y  Midwest_y  Mountain_y
2015-01-02   -18.0      -18.0       -35.0  -101.0      -97.0       -48.0
2015-01-09   -21.0      -33.0       -36.0  -122.0     -135.0       -50.0
2015-01-16   -31.0      -43.0       -34.0  -133.0     -154.0       -45.0
2015-01-23   -21.0      -19.0       -29.0  -113.0     -131.0       -40.0

This obviously doesn't return values (all entries filled with NaN):
df - dy

This addresses that but can only be used for dataframes with same number columns:
df - dy.iloc[:,:3].values

And then the natural extension (df - dy.values) complains about differing dimensions with error below.  How can I do this?
ValueError: Unable to coerce to DataFrame, shape must be (473, 3): given (473, 6)


I just fixed the formatting of the dataframes. Stack Exchange renders tabs as four spaces, which is why it was messed up. For tips for future questions, check out How to make good reproducible pandas examples and Fastest method to post a pandas dataframe from Jupyter Notebooks into a Stack Overflow problem? (still a bit of a work-in-progress IMHO)

You have to make sure your indices are aligned. Since this is not the case you can do it manually with reindex and convert to numpy array:
out = dy.rsub(df.reindex(index=dy.index, columns=dy.columns.str.extract('([^_]+)', expand=False)).values)

Output:
            East_5yavg  Midwest_5yavg  Mountain_5yavg  East_max  Midwest_max  Mountain_max
2015-01-02       -18.0          -18.0           -35.0    -101.0        -97.0         -48.0
2015-01-09       -21.0          -33.0           -36.0    -122.0       -135.0         -50.0
2015-01-16       -31.0          -43.0           -34.0    -133.0       -154.0         -45.0
2015-01-23       -21.0          -19.0           -29.0    -113.0       -131.0         -40.0

Another, cleaner, option would be to use a MultiIndex:
out = (dy.set_axis(dy.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
                     .rename(['location', None]),
                   axis=1)
         .rsub(df.rename_axis(columns='location'))
      )

Output:
location    East Midwest Mountain   East Midwest Mountain
           5yavg   5yavg    5yavg    max     max      max
2015-01-02 -18.0   -18.0    -35.0 -101.0   -97.0    -48.0
2015-01-09 -21.0   -33.0    -36.0 -122.0  -135.0    -50.0
2015-01-16 -31.0   -43.0    -34.0 -133.0  -154.0    -45.0
2015-01-23 -21.0   -19.0    -29.0 -113.0  -131.0    -40.0
2015-01-30   NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN
2015-02-06   NaN     NaN      NaN    NaN     NaN      NaN


not sure I follow re reindexing.  I've updated the question to make referenced dataframes consistent.  Indexes in each are identical.

@Chris, for the reindexing, I extracted the substrings before the _ (East/Midwest/Mountain) from the column names of dy. Then I used this to duplicate the columns of df in the same order. Finally I converted to stay array to avoid pandas automatic alignement (since I aligned manually).
